# How to redirect a user after a create method laravel6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I made a register form in the front_page and I want to redirect the user after a successfull registration to /home page, but instead I get an array and the user is not redirected.

```
  {"email":"example@example.com","paypal_email":"example@example.com","updated_at":"2020-02- 
  14 
  08:16:32","created_at":"2020-02-14 08:16:32","id":1}
```

My route:

```
 Route::post('/', 'Auth\RegisterController@create')->name('auth.register');
```

Register controller:

```
      public function create(Request $request)
{
    return User::create([
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'paypal_email' => $request['paypal_email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
    ]);


}    

  public $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Comment: Write return redirect('/home'); after create user in end of create function

Comment: please see my answer, it's not a good idea for using the `create` method directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    return User::create([
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'paypal_email' => $request['paypal_email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
    ]);


}
```

to this:

> ```
> public function create(Request $request) {
>     $create = User::create([
>         'email' => $request['email'],
>         'paypal_email' => $request['paypal_email'],
>         'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
>     ]);
>     if($create){
>        return redirect('/home');
>     }
>
>     //Return errors here  
> }
> ```

To learn more about laravel redirects, click [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects)

Answer (score 1):

You should not call the `create` method directly, for a few reasons.

1. the request is not being validated.
2. if you want to trigger some events during registration that is not going to happen.
3. it's not going auto-login the user.

The `create` method is really for laravel `trait RegistersUsers` internal usage. 
you can keep the controller like that, you only need to change your route to `register`.

```php
Route::post('/', 'Auth\RegisterController@register')->name('auth.register');
```

By doing this the user should be created and redirected to home page.

And there is a reason why `public $redirectTo = '/home';` this attribute exists, by  using the `create` method directly you are ignoring the attribute completely.